# +2 reputation for what

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-display

Yesterday it said +2 on the reputation tab in the top bar.

I opened the dropdown but there was no message, no suggested edit approved etc.

I don't even know on which site I earned those 2 rep.

Can anyone tell me? No downvotes were removed!

Comment: Could well be that some answers you downvoted were removed.

Comment: By "reputation tab", do you mean the tab on your profile? Then you'd know what site it was on. :) Or do you mean the "achievements" dropdown in the topbar?

Comment: @AdamLear The top bar. I've had it happen twice in the last two days and I've never had it happen before. Found this post a few minutes later. I had a screenshot open (but not saved), but my computer crashed a couple hours ago, so its lost. I didn't think of saving it after I saw this meta question.

Comment: @AdamLear I edited the question to make it clear

Answer (score 4):

There are notifications you receive about rep gains because of

- answers you downvoted were removed
- users who interacted with your posts were removed

these aren't really trackable from the rep [image] notification.

Regarding the removed questions, these won't be really trackable at your profile's reputation tab as well.

Comment: "User removed" is visible in the Achievements menu.

Comment: @iDebug That's why I mentioned only removed downvoted answers.